# Is instantiating a new Rectangle repeatedly slower than changing all its fields?

Tags: c#

Currently I have this code:

```
selectorRect.X = (e.X + hscTileset.Value) / tileLayer.TileSize * tileLayer.TileSize;
selectorRect.Y = (e.Y + vscTileset.Value) / tileLayer.TileSize * tileLayer.TileSize;

selectorRect.Width = 32;
selectorRect.Height = 32;
```

I am just changing all of the rectangle's fields. What if I did something like this?

```
selectorRect = new Rectangle((e.X + hscTileset.Value) / tileLayer.TileSize * tileLayer.TileSize, (e.Y + vscTileset.Value) / tileLayer.TileSize * tileLayer.TileSize, 32, 32)
```

I know the second line is a lot longer and less readable and generally not recommended but I'm still curious over the speed differences or its effects on the stack or heap. Since this code is within a control's MouseMove event handler it is called quite often and I'm wondering whether or not instantiating a new object that often will cause considerable speed differences.

Thanks!

Comment: Kind of answering my own question here but this thread gave me an idea (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch). Changing all the fields independently usually takes 3-16 TICKS. I had to use ticks because it kept coming up as 0 milliseconds. Instantiating a new object, however, took around 20-40 ticks. So apparently changing each field individually is not only more readable but faster as well (and probably better for memory)

Comment: you can't profile one operation: the way to time that is to time 1 MILLION such operations, and compare *that*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess, then since this is a `struct` I would expect them to be *about* the same. I would prefer the second ("new ...") for *semantic* reasons though - plus the first wouldn't work for a property (only a field/variable/array-lookup).

To get an exact measure : profile it *in your context*. I honesty doubt this will be a decision that makes a noticeable difference.